# ReferenceError:reponse is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I have a problem with response. I tried to research and could not find anything that helped.

Code:

```
 const { Client, RichEmbed } = require('discord.js')
 const Discord = require('discord.js')
  
 const bot = new Client()
  
 const ping = require('minecraft-server-util')
  
 const token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
  
 const PREFIX = '!'
  
 bot.on('ready', () =>{
     console.log('Bot has come online.')
 })
  
 bot.on('message', message =>{
  
     let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(' ')
  
     switch(args[0]){
         case 'mc':
  
             if(!args[1]) return message.channel.send('You must type a minecraft server ip')
             if(!args[2]) return message.channel.send('You must type a minecraft server port')
  
                 const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                 .setTitle('Server Status')
                 .addField('Server IP', reponse.host)
                 .addField('Server Version', reponse.version)
                 .addField('Online Players', reponse.onlinePlayers)
                 .addField('Max Players', reponse.maxPlayers)
                 
                 message.channel.send(Embed)
             }
  
     }
  
 )
```

Console:

```
 ReferenceError: reponse is not defined
     at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\status mc\mcserverbot.js:28:40)
     at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
     at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\status
```

> mc\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
> at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\status
> mc\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
> at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\status
> mc\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
> at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\status
> mc\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
> at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\status
> mc\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
> at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\status mc\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
> at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
> at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\status
> mc\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:825:20)
> PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\status mc>

Comment: What's `reponse`? Looks like a misspelling of `response` but that's also not defined anywhere.

Comment: If that token is used for authentication to authorize actions you would not like other people to be able to perform, you should remove it from stackoverflow.com following [this procedure](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258070/11107541).

Answer (score 0):

`reponse` is undefined because you aren't defining it anywhere